# R plotly, impossible to use the color parameter and have the text at the same time

Tags: r, text, colors, plotly

I have a plotly barplot in R but I can't manage to keep the colors of the bars by group and at the same time add the text at the top of the barplot. I've tried replacing the "color" parameter with "split" but the colors aren't in the right order.

```
library(plotly)
library(data.table)

dat = data.table(cat = rep("A", 6),
                 variable = c("a1", "b1", "c1", "a1", "b1", "c1"),
                 value = rnorm(6, 80, 40),
                 type = c("group", "group", "group", "overall", "overall", "overall")
)

plot_ly(
  data = dat,
  x = ~type,
  y = ~value,
  color = ~variable,
  colors = c(a1 = "#e06666", b1 = "#d0e0e3", c1 = "#93c47d"),
  type = 'bar',
  showlegend = TRUE,
  text = ~paste0(round(value), "%"),
  textposition = "auto"
)
```

Comment: Plotly is getting confused...if you use `dat$value` instead of `~value` it will give you what you're looking for: `text = paste0(round(dat$value), "%")` FYI, `textposition = "auto"` is usually just going to put the text in the tooltip (in addition to the x and y data). If you want the text on the plot, use another option, like `textposition = "outside"`.